# Creating a calendar with Java: Return Statement not returning any strings within nested for loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, arraylist, return

I'm currently trying to learn how to program, and I have started with Java. I would like to create a calendar, but I can't even seem to return any statements. When I run my code, nothing shows up. I realize my code may be very inefficient to anyone with experience, and I would appreciate any help.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CalendarSource {

    public ArrayList<String> calendarString = new ArrayList<String>(30);
    public ArrayList<Integer> calendarDay = new ArrayList<Integer>(30);
    public ArrayList<Integer> calendarMonth = new ArrayList<Integer>(12);

    public CalendarSource () {
    for (int x = 0; x < calendarMonth.size(); x++) { 
        calendarMonth.add(x);   
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < calendarString.size(); x++) {
        if (calendarString.indexOf(x) == 0 || x%7 == 0) {
            calendarString.add("Monday");
        }
        if (calendarString.indexOf(x) == 1 || x%7 == 1) {
            calendarString.add("Tuesday");
        }
        if (calendarString.indexOf(x) == 2 || x%7 == 2) {
            calendarString.add("Wednesday");
        }
        if (calendarString.indexOf(x) == 3 || x%7 == 3) {
            calendarString.add("Thursday");
        }
        if (calendarString.indexOf(x) == 4 || x%7 == 4) {
            calendarString.add("Friday");
        }
        if (calendarString.indexOf(x) == 5 || x%7 == 5) {
            calendarString.add("Saturday");
        }
        if (calendarString.indexOf(x) == 6 || x%7 == 6) {
            calendarString.add("Sunday");
        }
    }
    int x;  
}

public String getInfo() {
    int r;
    int c;
    for (int x = 0; x<calendarMonth.size(); x++)
        for (r = 0; r < 5; r++) {
            for (c = 0; c < 7; c++) {
                System.out.println(("placeholder  " + calendarString.get(c) + calendarMonth.get(x) + calendarDay.get(c)) );
            }
            System.lineSeparator();
        }
    return "testing text if nothing else returns";
    }
}
```

Here is the code I am using to test it, and I can't even get "testing text" to print out.

```
public class CalendarClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CalendarSource some= new CalendarSource();
        some.getInfo();
    }
}
```

Comment: All your `.size()` return `0` because `size()` returns number of elements not the capacity (which you set using constructor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a problem with the constructor.

The size of the array will always give you 0, unless you have a object inside, when you do like new ArrayList (12), you are no giving a size() to the arrayList.

istead of using the .size(0 in the constructor, you could use the number you  used to create the arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code has a lot of issues :

ArrayList(12) does not mean the ArrayList of size 12, but the Array List which will be able to accommodate 12 elements. So for all below ArrayLists size is still 0.

```
public ArrayList<String> calendarString = new ArrayList<String>(30);
public ArrayList<Integer> calendarDay = new ArrayList<Integer>(30);
public ArrayList<Integer> calendarMonth = new ArrayList<Integer>(12);
```

you can try it by using

```
public String getInfo() {
    int r;
    int c;
    System.out.println(calendarMonth.size());
    for (int x = 0; x < calendarMonth.size(); x++) {
        System.out.println("In Loop");
        for (r = 0; r < 5; r++) {
            for (c = 0; c < 7; c++) {
                System.out.println(("placeholder  " + calendarString.get(c) + calendarMonth.get(x) + calendarDay.get(c)));
            }
            System.lineSeparator();
        }
    }
    return "testing text if nothing else returns";
}
```

Comment: Updated the reason for it not working. Also for printing the return value you may need to `System.out.println(some.getInfo()) ;`